# Prove determinant of a matrix with trigonometry functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, determinant

I am a student. I am 15. Actually, I am a new learner of matrix & determinant. I have to prove an equation. I tried my best to solve this. But, I am failed.

**The equation is:**

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & \cos2\alpha & \sin\alpha \\
        1 & \cos2\beta& \sin\beta \\
        1 & \cos2\gamma & \sin\gamma \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 2(\sin\alpha - \sin\beta)(\sin\beta - \sin\gamma)(\sin\gamma - \sin\alpha)
$$

Thanks-

Comment: Hint (I have not tried). Multiply out the determinant (there will be six terms). Then use the double angle formula for the cosine.

Comment: Use $\cos2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha$ etc.

Comment: Convert all double angles to single angles. Then simplify/evaluate determinant.

Comment: Do you see how following Lord Shark's suggestion turns your determinant into a multiple of [a Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)?

Answer (score 2):

First idea: Make $0$'s in the first column. For example: $Row_2-Row_1$ and $Row_3-Row_1$

$$\text{Your det}=\begin{vmatrix} 1&\cos2\alpha&\sin\alpha\\ 0&\cos2\beta-\cos2\alpha&\sin\beta-\sin\alpha\\ 0&\cos2\gamma-\cos2\alpha&\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} \cos2\beta-\cos2\alpha&\sin\beta-\sin\alpha\\\cos2\gamma-\cos2\alpha&\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha\end{vmatrix}$$

Now, as @Ethan said in comments, try to use the double angle formula to continue.

Answer (score 2):

By the rule of SARRUS we get
$$\cos(2\beta)\sin(\gamma)+\cos(2\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\cos(2\gamma)\sin(\alpha)-\cos(2\alpha)\sin(\gamma)-\cos(2\gamma)\sin(\beta)-\cos(2\beta)\sin(\alpha)$$